# MySQLdump backup script no longer works, getting "mysqldump: unknown variable 'local-infile=0'"

Tags: mysql, bash, debian

I've recently upgrade a server to Debian 9 and MySQL to the latest version. I have a simple backup script that I run before performing any work on a production site but this time, when running my script, I encounter the following:

```
mysqldump: unknown variable 'local-infile=0'
```

Here is my script. What's going on?

```
#!/bin/bash
# [skipping commentary]

SITE=prod

# Set the directory that the Drupal root is IN, no trailing slashes
DROOT=[website_root]

# Set the directory for storing backups, no trailing slashes
BUD=/$DROOT/notes/backups

# Don't edit; End of defining variables
echo Doing a full back up...
echo Prepare to enter MySQL password...
# tar -czf $BUD/$SITE-files-$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S').tgz  $DROOT/docroot
mysqldump -u mysql_user -p drupal > $BUD/$SITE-drupal-$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S').sql
mysqldump -u mysql_user -p civicrm > $BUD/$SITE-civicrm-$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S').sql
ls -lh $BUD
pwd
echo Finished with backups...
```

MySQL version 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.6

Edit: When I ssh and run mysqldump with correct permissions I get the same issue. Weirdest thing, cron that runs similar process is backing up my databases as ordered.

Comment: check in `my.ini` for this variable. And if found comment it

Comment: Sorry, which variable? `local-infile`?

Comment: Right, check in mysql ini file for it

Comment: This worked, can you provide the reason why in an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the new version you install is compiled without support of `local-infile` parameter. And because package management system (usually) keep your current configuration file you can try to find this parameter in `my.ini` file and comment it.

This parameter manage `LOAD DATA LOCAL` functionality. But seems like this have some potential security issues ([more here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html))

Answer (score 5):

The best way to solve this is simply to rename the variable to: 
`loose-local-infile=1`

This will allow mysqldump to merely throw a warning, rather than a fatal error.

The suggestion to comment out the variable is not an option if you want LOAD DATA INFILE functionality out of the box, and MySQL 8+ for security reasons requires you to set this variable for *both* server (mysqld) and client. It is the [client] variable grouping in your config that chokes mysqldump if you don't add the "loose-" prefix to local-infile.

Comment: this seems to work only for the command line client (client section in config). If you use a custom section and read it programmatically (*-dev libraries) the prefix seems not to be recognized and the whole option is ignored.